# @sys-time inconsistency and improvements

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I don't know if is the best channel to talk about it, but I identified some inconsistency in @sys-time.

Maybe some dev could see and confirm or explain some hidden flag.
Obs: I tested using Portuguese Brazil workspace.

Input worked as @sys-time:

- 9h
- 09h
- 08:30
- 09:00:00h
- 08:30:00

Input does not worked as @sys-time:

- 9
- 09
- 08:30h

If 09h (using pattern h) is identified as a @sys-time, the 08:30h should be also.
The 9 or 09 are being identified as numbers but in a slot where the slot is expecting @sys-time it should be considered as @sys-time, not @sys-number.

I think if the slot is expecting some entity, the conversation/assistant engine should try to convert any input to that entity type.
"9" is a number. Right. But why in a slot context just "9" is not a valid hour if you are asking time?

Comment: You have 2 9h inputs ...

Comment: one 9h and another 09h. Just adjust the formatting. Thanks